# R - Adding missing observations before reshape a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Suppose I have following `data.frame`:

```
test <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,6), rep(2,3)),
monthYear = c("Dec16","Nov16","Oct16","Dec16","Nov16","Oct16","Dec16","Nov16","Dec16"),
color = c(rep("black", 4),rep("red",2),rep("black", 2),"red"),
quantity = c(1:9))
```

which results in this data.frame:

```
> test
  id monthYear color quantity
1  1     Dec16 black        1
2  1     Nov16 black        2
3  1     Oct16 black        3
4  1     Dec16 black        4
5  1     Nov16   red        5
6  1     Oct16   red        6
7  2     Dec16 black        7
8  2     Nov16 black        8
9  2     Dec16   red        9
```

For each `unique id` I need to create a subset of `color` by `monthYear`, where each monthYear is placed as a new column and quantity is aggregated accordingly:

```
library("reshape")
for (i in unique(test$id)) {
        subsetTest <- aggregate(cbind(quantity) ~ monthYear + color,
                                data = test[test$id==i,],
                                sum)
        subsetTestColumns <- reshape(subsetTest,
                                     timevar=as.character("monthYear"),
                                     idvar="color",
                                     direction="wide")
        names(subsetTestColumns)[-1]<-as.character(unique(subsetTest$monthYear))
        subsetTestColumns[is.na(subsetTestColumns)]<-0
        # Reorder by column name (just in case)
        subsetTestColumns[c("color", "Dec16", "Nov16","Oct16")]

        ### Do something with the resulting data.frame
}
```

For the first Id, the output is as expected:

```
> subsetTestColumns
  color Dec16 Nov16 Oct16
1 black     5     2     3
4   red     0     5     6
```

However, the `loop` fails for id=2 because there are not complete cases (Oct16 does not exist at all). Note that the structure of the resulting data.frame has to be exactly [color, Dec16, Nov16, Oct16]

I probably could check (before naming the monthYear columns) if all of the three
monthYears exist, and if not, create them manually. But somehow, I do not feel comfortable with this way.

I assume, that the best way to prevent the error would be adding the missing observations with zero quantities. Therefore, after creating the `subsetTest` data.frame with the `aggregate` function, I get following structure for id=2:

```
  monthYear color quantity
1     Dec16 black        7
2     Nov16 black        8
3     Dec16   red        9
```

In my opinion, adding 0 quantity to black for Oct16, and 0 quantity to red for Nov16 and Oct16 seems the more logic way to resolve the problem. Can you light me up on how to achieve this, taking into consideration that the original data has more than 100 ids and in each case the missing observations would be totally different?

Comment: Can't you just do `reshape2::dcast(test, id + color ~ monthYear, sum)`? Think it will much faster and easier.

Comment: Oh... felling so dumb :) it works perfect. Could you post the comment as an answer to accept it?